# Correct sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

please, can you help me ? Where I have a error in this sql syntax ? I am sorry for my english I am from czech republic.. I want to random search 12 products with pictures. When I delete "order by rand()" so search where products has pictures is working, but not working random function. And conversely, when I delete "where idObrazky is not null" so random search is working. But I want, that to work both. Thank you all for your help.

### **Query**

```
 SELECT eshop_dalsi_obrazky.*, eshop_zbozi.* 
 from eshop_zbozi 
 left join eshop_dalsi_obrazky 
 on (eshop_zbozi.idZbozi=eshop_dalsi_obrazky.eshop_zbozi_idZbozi) 
 where idObrazky is not null 
 LIMIT 12 order by rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your failure is that you have the `limit` before `order by` . please change it:

```
SELECT eshop_dalsi_obrazky.*, eshop_zbozi.* 
from eshop_zbozi left join eshop_dalsi_obrazky on (eshop_zbozi.idZbozi=eshop_dalsi_obrazky.eshop_zbozi_idZbozi) 
where idObrazky is not null order by rand() LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change place of Limit

```
SELECT eshop_dalsi_obrazky.*, eshop_zbozi.* from eshop_zbozi left join 
        eshop_dalsi_obrazky on (eshop_zbozi.idZbozi=eshop_dalsi_obrazky.eshop_zbozi_idZbozi)
         where idObrazky is not null LIMIT 12;
```

OR
you can try this also may be it helps you

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT eshop_dalsi_obrazky.*, eshop_zbozi.* from eshop_zbozi left join 
                eshop_dalsi_obrazky on (eshop_zbozi.idZbozi=eshop_dalsi_obrazky.eshop_zbozi_idZbozi)
                 where idObrazky is not null LIMIT 12) as tmpTbl  order by rand();
```

Comment: I tried this option before. Random function is working, but search products with pictures is not working... :-( but thank you

Comment: i didn't understand what your saying please explain in detail

Comment: When I use your option, so "idObrazky is not null" not working.

Comment: firstly mention the alias of table before attribute(like eshop_dalsi_obrazky.idObrazky) and in where use condition as "idObrazky<>null" May be it helps

Comment: its giving wrong output, random function is working, but products just with picture not working

Comment: check the above query.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER` comes before `LIMIT`. It should be:

```
SELECT 
    eshop_dalsi_obrazky . *, eshop_zbozi . *
from
    eshop_zbozi
        left join
    eshop_dalsi_obrazky ON (eshop_zbozi.idZbozi = eshop_dalsi_obrazky.eshop_zbozi_idZbozi)
where
    idObrazky is not null
order by rand()
LIMIT 12;
```

Comment: I tried this option before. Random function is working, but search products with pictures is not working... :-( but thank you

Comment: In the first place, what is the column that you want to sort out?